# Changing Components data in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a basic Example Component setup which is binded to a Vue Instance like so

```
<template>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Example Component</div>

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        {{ msg }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data : function(){
            return{
                msg : "Hello"
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

And this is my `app.js` file

```
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue'));

var firstComponent = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

This is my `HTML`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Laravel</title>


    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="app">
            <example-component></example-component>
        </div>

        <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I now change the value of `msg`? I don't have any reference to that component anywhere? How can I do that?

Is this possible?

```
var ex = Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue'));
ex.data = "new Value";
```

Comment: if remember correct `<example-component :message="Hello"></example-component>`  and add `message` to the props

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `props` property to your component and set inside it the `msg` property :

```
<script>
export default {
     props:{
         msg:{
            type:String,
            default:"Hello"
          }
       },
    data : function(){

    },
    mounted() {
        console.log('Component mounted.')
    }
  }
</script>
```

and

```
 <example-component msg="new Hello"></example-component>
```

**UPDATE**

after understanding your use case i recommend to use `child component ref`

```js
const ExampleComponent = Vue.component('example-component', {
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Example component</h2>
      <div>{{msg}}</div>
    </div>
  `,
  data() {
    return {
      msg: "Hello"
    }
  }
});

window.root = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    ExampleComponent
  }
});

root.$refs.example.msg = "new hello"
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="app">
    <h2>Parent</h2>

    <example-component ref="example"></example-component>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** Have a look at this example, it does what you want: https://codesandbox.io/s/88ojwpjq88

You need to distinguish between `data` (the components private data) and `props` (data passed to the child component). Read this section of the Vue.js guide: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html

In your component, you'll need to declare the prop:

```
export default {
    props : ['msg'],
    mounted() {
        console.log('Component mounted.')
    }
}
```

Then you can bind a data to the child component like this:
`<example-component :msg="myMessage"></example-component>`, assuming the parent component has `myMessage` declared like this:

```
data : function(){
   return {
    myMessage : "Hello"
  }
}
```

To change the value, you can bind it to some sort of input. Here's an example w/ a text field: `<input v-model="myMessage">`.

If you enter sth. into this field, you should see the bound value in your component update.

Do read the manual here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/index.html. It's really good, your questions are covered entirely in there.

Comment: Alright, but my question is how to change the value of parent msg? If I do `firstComponent` is says undefined in console.

Answer (score 0):

Add the property to your component, make it parent-to-child, that is, you will bind the property within the component, and you can pass data to that property.
Depending on the flow, you must identify how you will do this, whether it is from father to son or from child to father. To pass data to child, you pass through props, if you pass from child to parent, you will use $ emit.
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props

If you use parent to child you will do it the following way.
Pai.vue

```
<template>
  <div> {{msg}} </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
 props: {
  msg: {
  type: String,
  default: 'Hello'
  }
 }
}
</script>
```

Ai Inside the child component you call the parameter

```
<template>
 <div>
  <parent :msg="valueMsg"/>
 </div>
</template>
```

enter code here

son.vue

```
<script>
import pai from './pai'
export default {components: {parent},
 data: () => ({
  valueMsg = 'Hello Test'
  })
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hamiltongabriel/3zr8jb7r/